What is causing white staining on natural quartzite countertops caused by baking soda poultice?
Help! I recently tried to remove some oil stains from my quartzite countertop using a poultice of baking soda and water for 8hrs overnight (after doing a of research and finding the whole internet suggesting this method!). Unfortunately it brightened the stone and made the oil stains appear even worse! What is causing this brightness effect, and is there a way to resolve it? Appreciate any help!
https://imgur.com/a/snkOcrK
https://imgur.com/a/UBpMGI1

What are we supposed to be seeing in your pics?

Hi! Thanks for your response. If you see closely that there is a slightly lighter spot where the poultice used to be. I’ve circled it in the below photo. But if it’s hardly visible then maybe I should just develop a blind eye for it ;) https://imgur.com/a/OTiWKxj

Here another image in case it helps.
https://imgur.com/a/RUImiiu

If the spots have to be highlighted to be noticed, I would not worry about them.

it is unclear why baking soda would dissolve grease ... you need soap for that ... the soap molecule attaches to fat at one end and attaches to water at the other end ... that's how soap works, it allows fat to be flushed away

Quartzite is a natural stone. Some types of quartzites require sealing. Is your quartzite sealed? If not, this could explain the brightening.
